# Komma zwischen Adjektiven/ Adverbien

Tags: punctuation

> Durch das Fördern neuer kleiner Lebenskreise, Mehrgenerationenfamilien, Nachbarschaften, Stadtteile, Hilfsgruppen aller Art werden die **großen, häufig** ineffizienten staatlichen Sozialbürokratien sinnvoll ergänzt, die wir uns in Anbetracht der demografischen Entwicklung ohnehin wahrscheinlich bald nicht mehr leisten können.

Warum gibt es hier in der dritten Zeile ein Komma zwischen *großen* und *häufig*? Sind sie getrennte Sätze oder Adjektive für *Sozialbürokratien*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es sind beides Adjektive für "Sozialbürokratien". Das Komma hätte auch durch ein "und" ersetzt werden können:
*… Hilfsgruppen aller Art werden die großen **und** häufig ineffizienten staatlichen Sozialbürokratien sinnvoll ergänzt, …*

Hope it helps.

Holger

Comment: kleine Anmerkung: `häufig` ist in diesem Fall nicht wirklich ein Adjektiv sondern ein Adverb und bezieht sich auf `ineffizienten`, welches das Adjektiv für Sozialbürokratien ist.

Comment: @Cashbee  danke schön mein/e Lehrer/in

Comment: @Holger Handreck meinen Sie dass häufig ist ein Adjektive nur für ineffizient also warum gibt es und bevor  bevors Wort staatlich. es ist das letzte Adjektive für Sozial...